# “the mathematical writings of Archimedes” – what if the definite article were removed?

Tags: articles

> Unlike his inventions, **the** mathematical writings of Archimedes were little known in antiquity.

Would the meaning of this sentence change if the definite article were removed:

> Unlike his inventions, mathematical writings of Archimedes were little known in antiquity.

Comment: I think *part* of the reason for native speakers expecting a "determiner" (the definite article ***the***) in the cited context is to maintain consistency with preceding ***his*** (also a determiner). Curiously though, I ***wouldn't*** expect that definite article if the preposition ***of*** were changed to ***by*** - in which context it would also be fine by me to discard the preceding determiner as well: *Unlike [his] inventions, mathematical writings **by** Archimedes were little known in antiquity.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't state a clear difference in meaning, but if you make this statement in the context of specific writings that are known today, then, to me, it seems more adequate to use "the".